# Dynamically outputting liquid object using loop index

Tags: shopify, liquid

I have been trying to iterate an output of a section using variables, but I cannot find a way to output the liquid object dynamically by concatenating the index. `images[i]` is the id of the image that I set in the `{% schema %}` section.

```
{% for i in (1 .. 5) %}

{% if section.settings.images[i] != blank %}
    {{ section.settings.image[i] }}
{% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost there.

You need to assign the handle/id, since at the moment `images[i]` points to an array of images which is not correct.

The code should be something like this:

```
{% for i in (1 .. 5) %}
  {% assign image_handle = 'images' | append: i %}
  {% if section.settings[image_handle] != blank %}
      {{ section.settings[image_handle] }}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Assuming that your images ID are called `images1`, `images2`, `images3` etc..

PS:

I'm not sure of your full code, but if you have a section and if you're not using its blocks why don't you use them instead of predefined sections fields?

```
{%- for block in section.blocks -%}
  {%- if block.settings.image != blank -%}
    {{ block.settings.image | img_url: '600x' | img_tag }}
  {%- endif -%}
{%- endfor -%}

{% schema %}
{
  "name": "Images",
  "max_blocks": 5,
  "blocks": [
    {
      "type": "image",
      "name": "Image",
      "settings": [
        {
          "type": "image_picker",
          "id": "image",
          "label": "Image"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
{% endschema %}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You gave me the answer I was looking for that I didn’t know I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I want this code exactly, Thank you very much...

This is my sample code.

```
{% for i in (1..10) %}
    {% assign display_brand = 'display_brand_' | append: i %}
    {% assign image_handle = 'image_' | append: i %}
    {% assign link_handle = 'link_' | append: i %}
        {% if block.settings[display_brand] %}
        <div class="brand-item">
            <div class="brand-top">
                {% if block.settings[image_handle] != blank %}
                    <img src="{{ block.settings[image_handle] | img_url: '350x' }}" alt="" />
                {% else %}
                    <div class="not_img">
                        350 x 375px
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
            <a href="{{block.settings[link_handle]}}" class="btn">{% render 'multilang' with block.settings.itembuttontext %}</a>
        </div>
        {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```